# realtime communication with ruby

Tags: ruby, polling

I'm about to write a game server with ruby. One feature of the game includes player walking around & others should be able to see it.

I've already written a pure socket demo using event machine. But since most of the communication are going to be http-based, so I'm looking for some http polling solution. And of course I could write it with event machine, but is there any gem out there for this kind of job already?

I've tried something like faye, but most of these are for a messaging system, like subscribing & publish to a channel, I seem not to be able to control what clients I should push to. In my case I need to be able to push to specific clients, like one guy moves from 10,10 to 20,20, only those around him (maybe from 0,0 to 30,30, but not a guy at 40,50) need to receive the message.

------------pregress with cramp

Here's a quick update. I'm working on cramp, with 5000 connections, and 100 client move each second, the CPU usage is almost 100%. When I double both figures, the CPU usage is still 100% or so, and the response is very slow.

Clearly I'm not using every resource I had, instead there's only one CPU core occupied. Need more work on it.

------------Node.js's turn

@aam1r 
Actually Node.js is doing better than cramp. With 5000 connections and 100 client moving per seoncd, the Cpu usage is over 60%. When I doubled to 10000 connections and 200 client moving per second, the CPU usage is 100% and response is becoming slow. Same problem here, either cramp or Node.js can only use one cpu core per process. That's a problem.

------------What about JRuby?

Because of the presence of [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), there's no true multi-thread simultanious execution with Ruby MRI. None with Node.js either.So I'm going to give JRuby a try.

- When a client moves, use another thread to find all the other clients need to notify(which is a CPU-heavy work). Then push the result to a channel.
- The main thread simply subscribes the channel. When it gets the result, push them to the clients.

Need some time to write a demo though.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Espresso](http://e.github.com/) with Server-Sent Events.

On the server-side you define a streaming action:

```
class App < E
  map :/

  attr_reader :connections

  def subscribe
    @connections ||= []
    stream :keep_open do |conn|
      connections << conn
      conn.callback { connections.delete conn }
    end
  end

  private
  def communicate_to_clients
    connections.each do |conn|
      conn << 'some message'
    end
end
```

The :keep_open option will instruct the server to not  close connection.

Then open a connection with Javascript:

```
pool = new EventSource('/subscribe');
pool.on_message = function(msg) {
  // here you receive messages sent by server
  // via communicate_to_clients method
}
```

Comment: Wow how come I've never heard of espresso? I've planned to use Sinatra for most of the server end stuff, but espresso looks like a good alternative. However as for the realtime stuff, correct me if I'm wrong, like other frameworks, espresso needs a separate process to handle each request right? If so, say I have 1000 players online, then I'd need 1000 processes, each for a single player, I don't think that's gonna work.

Comment: @DeanWinchester, not sure why you think you need multiple processes. A single Espresso process can handle any number of requests. In the example i shown a single Espresso process adding connections to a pool and communicate to them when needed.

Comment: oh then I'd be wrong. I thought it was like other frameworks, rails or sinatra, using a single process to handle each request. I'll take a closer look at it.

Comment: The project seems to have vanished from the face of the earth.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using polling. Polling would result in too much overhead since you'll be making new connections every time make a new request. Also, it won't be real-time enough for you (i.e. you will poll every X seconds -- not instantly)

Instead, I would suggest using something like [Cramp](http://cramp.in/). From their website:

> Cramp is a fully asynchronous real-time web application framework in
>   Ruby. It is built on top of EventMachine and primarily designed for
>   working with larger number of open connections and providing
>   full-duplex bi-directional communication.

All your clients would maintain a persistent connection through which they can send/receive messages. There won't be overhead of making a new connection every time and messages will be sent in real-time since clients won't be checking "every X seconds".

You can also use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) instead of Cramp. It's a Javascript framework that can be used to develop real-time applications.

Here are some more resources that should help you out:

- [Slideshow on using Node.js with Ruby](http://www.slideshare.net/mbleigh/nodejs-and-ruby)
- [Discussion on "Real time ruby apps: CRAMP vs NODE.JS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785531/real-time-ruby-apps-cramp-vs-node-js)

Comment: Cramp looks promising.I'll try it out later.As for Node.js, I read an article, comparing the performance of it and event machine, it's just terrible. I'm not sure if it's that bad. Do you happen to have any experience with Node.js performance?

Comment: @DeanWinchester: I've played around with the Node.js framework but have never built something that required me to worry about performance. I would search for benchmarks and/or results posted by people who've actually used Node for online multiplayer games.

Comment: I should probably write a demo myself, maybe tomorrow. And I'll keep you posted.

Comment: In case you're still concerned about this, here's a quick update. I'm still working on cramp, and right now as soon as the connection exceeds 1024, the cpu usage goes right to 100%. I think it's something about thin, and I'm googling around right now.
PS:How come I can't @ you?

Comment: @DeanWinchester: Seems like you'll have to start tuning your webserver for a high number of connections. If you're stuck with performance tuning, I would suggest asking for help at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). (Not sure about the @ btw).

Comment: Well it's actually about the default config of thin, not a big deal. 'thin --help' show everything. LOL